# Cast column to differnent datatype before performing evaluation in pyarrow dataset filter

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

In a less than ideal situation, I have values within a parquet dataset that I would like to filter, using > = < etc, however, because of the mixed datatypes in the dataset as a whole, it seems the field is read as an object.

Is there a way to cast the column to a different datatype before evaluating:

I.e. ds.field('value').cast('uint8') > 60 to become part of the filter list?

```py
ParquetDataset(folder, use_legacy_dataset=False, filters=[('group','==',group),('table','==',table),(ds.field('value').cast('uint8') > 60)]).read().to_pandas()
```

I tried the method above and didn't seem to work, it just returns the:

> TypeError: object of type 'pyarrow._compute.Expression' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

The [dataset api](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/dataset.html) can filter on expressions.

```py
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

expr = (ds.field('group') == group) & (ds.field('table') == table) & (ds.field('value').cast('uint8') > 60)
ds.dataset(folder).to_table(filter=expr).to_pandas()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error:

```py
(ds.field('value').cast('uint8') > 60)
```

This return an expression which isn't what you want. You want a tuple:

```py
(ds.field('value').cast('uint8'), ">", 60)
```

That's why it complains about `TypeError: object of type 'pyarrow._compute.Expression' has no len()`, it was expecting a tuple

PS:

> it seems the field is read as an object.

There are no `object` in pyarrow, I don't think you need to cast.